# How can I access the Bazel Cache Directory in a .bzl file?

Tags: bazel

For some background, my specific use case is actually in Rules Python's compile_pip_requirements rule. I do not want to use the default caching location for pip packages, so I am passing args to pip through compile_pip_requirements via:

```
compile_pip_requirements(
...

extra_args = [
            "--allow-unsafe",
            "--cache-dir",
            "/tmp/pip-compile",
        ],
...)
```

I can easily hardcode the tmp dir there, but I would like to specifically use the same directory that Bazel uses to cache everything else, without making any magic assumptions about where that cache dir is.

I have tried to use `$(bazel info | grep output_base | awk '{print $2}')` but Bazel appears to only accept its own Make Variables within a variable expression, not to mention that this does not feel like a safe option anyway.

I have also tangled a bit with those make variables (most promisingly, `$(location //foo)`), but it seems this only returns the location of a given module relative to WORKSPACE.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, bazel's CAS (content addressable storage) will cache input / output blobs via their hashes (generally sha256).  Therefore, just pointing your pip cache at bazel's cache might not work as expected.  I don't think there's guarantees on how bazel will handle that folder.  Nonetheless, I can see the motivation, because then you only have to worry about 1 cache, and nothing in your system temp.  Maybe $OUTPUT_BASE is available during rule execution?

Comment: @TrevorHickey I had the same thought with respect to $OUTPUT_BASE -- it doesn't appear to work, same issue as the variable expression above. I had a feeling that might be the case and that I'd have to make some assumptions about cache folder locations, but I will look into some genrule trickery next. Thanks for the suggestion.